# Li's displayed inline take up more space in IE7?

Tags: internet-explorer-7

I have some li's that are displayed inline. They have horizontal margin and padding in the form of ems.

This is fine in all browsers except for IE7 where they are too wide to fit in the container and go onto 2 lines.

Does IE7 render text at a different size to other versions of IE? Using the IE developer tools I cant see any different CSS being applied. I took a screengrab of the page and I can see the container is the same but the text takes up more space in IE7 than 8 or 9.

UPDATE in the screengrab I can see the individual words are longer in IE7 than other browsers.

Comment: Can you post a minimal example with HTML and CSS? I believe the problem is due to some whitespace; I've seen similar things in IE9.

Comment: We really need to see those screenshots, or the code, to be able to help in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes ie renders them differently, specifically the bullets in firefox are rendered outside of the padding (or vice versa)

try:

```
li {
  white-space: nowrap; // stop the wrapping in the first place
}
```

Comment: There are minute differences in how text is rendered by different browsers, even with your css solution.

Comment: I was thinking normalizr.js is the answer for this, the goal of their solution is to normalize differences between browsers. Other possible answers include setting a fixed width to the element and fixed margins/padding (maybe with text-align right).. a larger line-height style might work, box-sizing:border-box; might work, list-style:none might help also.